# Treacle is viscous; alcohol is ____?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, antonyms

What's the best adjective to describe the low viscosity of liquids such as water and alcohol?

One that came to mind is 'runny', but then some honeys are runny, despite actually being inherently viscous. Also 'thin' seems somewhat unsatisfactory when describing a liquid.

Comment: ..........yummy?

Comment: What about Guinness or London Porter? The more foam there is the more viscous it is. This article from the Daily Mail may be interesting. Why does coffee get spilled more often than beer? http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-2847545/So-s-coffee-spills-easily-beer-foam-drink-contains-likely-slosh-around.html

Comment: Alcohol is *not*.

Comment: Volatile, perhaps?

Comment: @mikeTheLiar: "volatile" means "easily evaporated", which is likely *correlated* to unviscousness, but not the same thing.

Comment: @Eric I know, which is why it's a comment instead of an answer and decorated with "perhaps" and a question mark.

Comment: "Alcohol flows easily."

Comment: I think "delicious" is better than yummy, because it rhymes.

Comment: @Nicholas candy is dandy but liquor is quicker.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar touché

Comment: Is there anything wrong with "low viscosity" itself?  I realize you seem to be looking for a single word but not every property has one.

Comment: Just go with runny. It describes the fluidity fairly concisely; I don't see any misinterpretation here, nor is it slang.

Comment: *"Also 'thin' seems somewhat unsatisfactory when describing a liquid."* - Seems fine to me. You can have "thick" liquids ("Blood is thicker than water", "I drank a thickshake"), so why not "thin"?

Comment: Hmm... "Deliscous" ? :P

Comment: Treacle is viscous; alcohol is vicious. Almost the same thing.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with **thin**. One might inspissate a thin broth, take Coumadin as a blood thinner, lubricate a pinion with a thin oil and so on. **Watery** might work in some circumstances, but it's more ambiguous since it is often used to refer to flavor.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I think "watery" would more often mean "heavily diluted in water," especially for something like alcohol, which is often diluted in water. Thin works, though.

Comment: @trlkly One could coin *water-thin*, in analog to [water-clear](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/water-clear).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Which is the best answer will depend partly on the degree of formality (i.e. what register) you are aiming for. Centaurus's suggestion of *inviscid* is very suitable in an academic or scientific context, but for general purposes you might consider either *runny* or *free-flowing.*

You are right, of course, to say that some honeys are *runny*; but the implication of using that term is not that those honeys have a particularly low viscosity, but only that they flow much more readily than stiff honeys.

Comment: I think you're right about 'runny'.

Comment: Who has ever heard of a *runny bear* or *wine being runny*? On the other hand, *running* would fit better e.g. *running water*

Answer (score 36):

I think you are looking for **"inviscid"** (having very low viscosity) or **"mobile"**

> - **inviscid** (adj) - "having negligible, or zero, viscosity" -  [**TFD**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/inviscid)

In common parlance, a fluid that has zero viscosity is known as **an inviscid fluid**.  A liquid is said to be viscous if its viscosity is substantially greater than water's, and may be described as **mobile** if the viscosity is noticeably less than water's.

> - **mobile** (adj) Characterized by an extreme degree of fluidity; moving or flowing with great freedom. - [**Wikipedia**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mobile)

- He covers governing equations, ideal-fluid flow, **viscous** flows of incompressible fluids, the compressible flow of **inviscid** fluids, and methods of mathematical analysis.
- Mercury is a **mobile** liquid.

Comment: So is 'mobile' the word then? Because 'inviscid' seems to be the opposite of 'solid'.

Comment: I'm not sure about this. If 'inviscid' means "having zero viscosity", then water and alcohol can't be inviscid. The only things that have zero viscosity as far as I know are superfluids such as liquid helium.

Comment: Better: negligible viscosity.

Comment: How about "relatively inviscid"?

Comment: I don't think that "inviscid" is a good answer to this question. No non-super fluid is "inviscid"; at best, a real fluid may be "of low viscosity" (or "relatively inviscid", as Hot Licks suggests). I certainly have never heard a fluid being called "inviscid" in "common parlance" - are all the people you talk to physicists?

Comment: In a casual context, I'd expect "runny" rather than "inviscid". Vaguer, but more likely in common speech.

Comment: That excerpt pretty clearly states that “mobile” is the correct term.

Comment: This is the word I was given in my chemistry classes many years ago for such fluids.  However, I think Merriam-Webster may have overstated the meaning with "zero viscosity," as this word was used *well* before any super fluids were discovered (1890's on Google's ngrams engine).  I think the Merriam-Webster version may come from its Engineering usage, which is better phrased "negligible viscosity," where solving problems involves setting all viscosity terms to zero to simplify the equations.

Comment: @CortAmmon Granted, the term was coined before superfluids were known, but my understanding is that in those days, it was still used to describe an idealized fluid that does not actually exist (as in "first, assume a spherical cow in a vacuum"). Compare "frictionless": just as we would not use "frictionless" to describe something that is only "very smooth", I also do not think it makes much sense to use "inviscid" to describe something that is only "very non-viscous".

Answer (score 30):

I suggest  [fluid](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Fluid): (from TFD)

> - (General Physics) capable of flowing and easily changing shape

Comment: This was my natural reaction to the question title if you want colloquial/natural voice

Comment: A viscous fluid is still a fluid though.

Comment: A viscous fluid is still a fluid, but perhaps it is not a fluid fluid.

Comment: "Fluid" is not the correct term. The air is a fluid (gases are fluids, as are liquids). For that matter, silly putty is a fluid (a highly viscoelastic fluid), and no one would call silly putty "runny".

Comment: @DavidHammen: You are thinking of the noun form of *fluid*, which as you say is not a good fit, but Josh61 is thinking of the adjective, which does mean "capable of flowing".

Comment: Lava is capable of flowing, but slowly. So is treacle, and so is silly putty. Being fluid (adjective, capable of flowing) is what distinguishes fluids (noun) from non-fluids. I stand by my comment and downvote. This is not the right answer.

Comment: @DavidHammen and glass is also fluid, in the extreme case...

Comment: @smci That's actually a myth, glass isn't a fluid/liquid unless molten: http://io9.com/the-glass-is-a-liquid-myth-has-finally-been-destroyed-496190894

Comment: @BrianDHall Oh, I'd thought that experiment affirmed it flowed.

Comment: @smci, Experiment proved it didn't flow, as well as observation of the many, many panes of glass that kept their thick edge up for centuries. The myth has [been debunked](http://dwb.unl.edu/Teacher/NSF/C01/C01Links/www.ualberta.ca/~bderksen/florin.html) several times.

Answer (score 13):

All fluids are viscous. Some fluids have low viscosity, while other fluids have high viscosity. I'm not aware of a common word, even a common technical word, that will fit in your blank.  "Inviscid," from another answer, is not in common use and conjures a technical meaning that I don't think you're after.

A similar example from the sciences: all objects contain heat. The analogy is that "viscosity" is to "viscous" as "heat" is to "hot"; you're searching for "cold," but I don't know that you'll find it.

I would abandon the parallelism and describe what the fluids do: treacle is viscous, but alcohol *flows freely*.

Comment: I was about to say this same thing. From a scientific perspective, all liquids are viscous/have viscosity. All matter that has a temperature above absolute zero are hot/have heat. "Cold" is a subjective term. Liquids simply have more or less viscosity than other liquids. Alcohol/water/liquor have low viscosities/are not highly viscous.

Answer (score 9):

If you want an adjective, I'd suggest "liquid" or "fluid", though "a thin liquid"  is entirely correct idiomatically

Comment: Both "liquid" and "fluid" apply to treacle.

Comment: @nnnnnn: As nouns, yes. As adjectives, not in my usage.

Answer (score 4):

Use ["watery" (Ref: Dictionary.com)](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/watery):

> 8.
>   resembling water in fluidity and absence of viscosity:
>   "a watery fluid."

This is technically correct, easily understood, and quite often applies in more than one sense ("watery soup", for example).

---

"Dilute" also applies in some contexts (Solutions, colloids, the aforementioned soup or honey).

Comment: [According to Google](https://www.google.nl/search?q=antonym+viscous), "watery" is also the antonym of "viscous".

Answer (score 2):

*Thin* is sometimes used in this context as an antonym to *thick*.